# Gulp Error: not found: notify-send (Ubuntu)

Tags: sass, gulp

I am trying to compile the scss theme with gulp on Ubuntu 18.04 OS and I get this error:

```
Error: not found: notify-send
    at getNotFoundError (/home/user/stack-admin-v4.0/stack-admin/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
    at Function.whichSync [as sync] (/home/user/stack-admin-v4.0/stack-admin/node_modules/which/which.js:134:9)
    at NotifySend.notify (/home/user/stack-admin-v4.0/stack-admin/node_modules/node-notifier/notifiers/notifysend.js:65:27)
    at notifyCssTask (/home/user/stack-admin-v4.0/stack-admin/gulp-tasks/notify.js:5:21)
    at bound (domain.js:419:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:432:12)
    at asyncRunner (/home/user/stack-admin-v4.0/stack-admin/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:76:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I had to install `libnotify-bin`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnotify-bin
```